# Speed up a MySQL query that times out

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I am trying to get data from multiple tables that need to be consolidated together for reporting.  I am trying to get all the details of every header that is complete after a certain date and must check for the 0 date because of bad data.

I am working with legacy tables that I, sadly, did not create and cannot change.  This statement times out in my application and takes about 40 seconds to run against a database on a local Virtual Machine.  Is it possible to refactor the query for better performance?  Any help is appreciated!

```
SELECT detail.* 
FROM detail 
JOIN header 
  ON detail.invoice = header.invoice 
WHERE detail.dateapply != '0000-00-00' 
  AND header.dateapply >= '2017-09-17' 
  AND header.orderstatus IN ('complete', 'backorder') 
ORDER BY detail.DateApply;`
```

Comment: What field type is `dateapply`?

Comment: Do you have index on dateapply and orderstatus?

Comment: The sane thing would be to add proper indices to the tables being joined and filtered. But since you cannot change the tables … you are out of luck I guess? Unless adding indices does not count as "cannot change"

Comment: `SELECT detail.* FROM detail JOIN (SELECT * FROM header WHERE header.dateapply >= '2017-09-17' AND header.orderstatus IN ('complete', 'backorder')) AS h WHERE ON detail.invoice = h.invoice WHERE detail.dateapply != '0000-00-00' AND  ORDER BY detail.DateApply;`
try to decrease the number of scanning rows and create indexes if they missed

Comment: When asking questions about query optimization, you should always post the `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each table referenced in the query, and also post the current `EXPLAIN` for the query. Help us help you!

Comment: @JNevill dateapply is a date

Comment: usually I will try to remove parts of the query and play around to see which part is slowing it down.Also, sometimes it's better to use unions instead of in.

Comment: @sskoko sadly, there are no indexes on these

Comment: Can't you add index?

Comment: _Why_ can't you "change the tables"?  `ALTER TABLE` is what it takes.

Comment: @RickJames My employers customers each have their own local servers with various Ubuntu versions and MySQL versions.  Our DBA is uncomfortable with updating all of the customers tables at this point.  I will continue to try and talk them into doing so.

Comment: The same `ALTER TABLE` commands will work on all versions of MySQL/MariaDB.

Answer (score 1):

For `header`:

```
INDEX(orderstatus, dateapply)
INDEX(invoice, orderstatus, dateapply)
```

For `detail`:

```
INDEX(invoice, dateapply)
INDEX(dateapply, invoice)
```

The ordering of the columns is deliberate.  Since I can't tell which table the Optimizer will start with, I provided indexes that should be optimal either way.

If the two `dateapply` columns are in sync, then there are probably further optimizations.

Answer (score -1):

Between my coworker and myself we came up with the below query that is returning results more quickly.  The GROUP BY eliminated duplicate records.  I would like to thank everyone for taking the time to help me look at my issue and look forward to the possibility of using indexes in the future.

```
SELECT d.* 
FROM detail d 
JOIN header h 
   ON d.invoice = h.invoice 
WHERE d.qbposted = 0 
   AND d.dateapply != '0000-00-00' 
   AND h.dateapply >= '2017-09-17' 
   AND h.orderstatus IN ('complete', 'backorder') 
GROUP BY d.rec ORDER BY d.dateapply;
```